# Does editing a release definition change a release in progress?

Tags: tfs

I have a release in progress that completed environment 1 but still needs approval for environment 2.

Now, if I change the steps for environment 2 in the release definition will the existing release execute the old or the new steps for environment 2?

Comment: No, the it will use the previous pipeline definition (at the time you created it) for releases already in progress.  You can edit the specific release that's in progress though, but then those changes aren't applied to the definition/pipeline for other releases.

Comment: @DanielMorritt Great! If you put that into an answer, I can accept it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit an individual release in progress, but this change is not applied to the overall pipeline or any other releases.

Editing the overall release pipeline while a deployment is in progress (even if waiting on approval etc) also does not affect the existing releases in progress.

In your case, you either have to apply the change to the release pipeline *and* the release in progress, or update the pipeline, cancel the release in progress and start a new one.